# Is it possible to compile angular template to final html string?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is it possible to compile this html template string:

```
"<p>List of products from {{supplier.name}}</p>
<p ng-repeat="ref in refs">{{ref}}</p>"
```

directly to an html string like:

```
"<p>List of products from Some Supplier</p>
<p>a0120</p>
<p>a0241</p>
<p>z1242</p>
<p>z3412</p>"
```

or at least the less clean version:

```
"<p class="ng-scope ng-binding">List of product from Duval</p>
<!-- ngRepeat: ref in refs track by $index -->
<p ng-repeat="ref in refs track by $index" class="ng-scope ng-binding">a0120</p>
<p ng-repeat="ref in refs track by $index" class="ng-scope ng-binding">a0241</p>
<p ng-repeat="ref in refs track by $index" class="ng-scope ng-binding">z1242</p>
<p ng-repeat="ref in refs track by $index" class="ng-scope ng-binding">z3412</p>"
```

I tried using $compile(templateStr)($scope) but the dom elements returned are not fully processed.
However I managed no compile it to a page element using the following directive and and inspecting that element I can see it has the final html I'm looking for:

```
app.directive('compile', function($compile) {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            compile: '=compile',
            data: '=ngData'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('data',
                    function(value) {
                        for (var k in scope.data)
                            scope[k] = scope.data[k];
                    }
            )

            scope.$watch('compile',
                    function(value) {
                        element.html(value);
                        var a = $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                    }
            )
        }
    }
})
```

Is there any way I can get that final html directly from the template?
Thanks

PS:
What I'm trying to achieve here is to edit a template directly in CKEditor (in text mode, not source)
and only eventually goint to source mode to add some "ng-repeat" attributes.
Using template engines like Handlebars require placeholders outside html elements and are automaticaly erased by CKEditor since it only deals with html.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION (hacky):
One possible way is to use the compile directive on an hidden element and read the element's content after view is loaded on the controller:

> ```
> $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', $scope.onLoaded);
> $timeout(function() {
>     var el =$("#text div")[0]
>     cleanAngularStuff(el)
>     $scope.currMailTemplate.processed = el.innerHTML
> });
> ```

The cleanAngularStuff function is just to clean extra angular directives and classes.

I'll post it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371540/how-to-clean-html-from-angular-directives-and-helper-comments/19405732#19405732) if someone wants to use it or improve it.

Any better way to do this without adding an element to the page?

Comment: I tried that but I want to use an ckeditor (or similar) to edit the template and these editor only allow html elements.
Addind {{#each ref}} outside an element tag is automatically erased

Comment: @RuiFortes it depends on when you want what's been compiled. What are you trying to achieve by having the html output of angular?

Comment: just added some explanation to original post

Comment: I don't really understand why you're binding to `'compile'` on your scope... is there some compile object on your controller's scope? And what does `$scope.data` look like in your controller?  I guess just some more context would be helpful.

Comment: @tennisgent compile is a directive.
See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile
I just change it to use a isolated scope. I also used some hacky strategy to extract passes "data" object properties to the scope root just so I don't have to prefix all template placeholders

Comment: RuiFortes did u get a solution to this. I also need the output as a string

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is access the compiled element after a $digest cycle.

So within a $digest cycle you can do:

```
templateString = '<some-template-code/>';
...
var compiled = $compile(templateString)(scope);
// scope.$digest // only call this if not within a $digest cycle

// you can do a $timeout to let the previous digest cycle complete
$timeout(function(){
  var theHtml = compiled[0].outerHTML;
  console.log('the html with the variables', theHtml);
});
```

If you aren't already within a digest cycle then you need to manually call `scope.$digest()`.  You can see the embedded sample below.

```js
(function(){
  "use strict";
  var app = angular.module('soApp', []);
  
  app.directive('showCompiledTemplate',[
            '$compile','$timeout',
    function($compile , $timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="compiled-template">' +
           '<div><textarea cols="40" rows="15" readonly></textarea></div>' +
             '<div class="output"></div>' +
                  '</div>',
        scope: {
          data: '=',
          template: '='
        },
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
            var textarea = elem.find('textarea')[0];
            var output = elem.children().children().eq(1);
   var updateOutput = function(tpl) {
                var compiled = $compile(tpl)(scope);
                $timeout(function(){
                    var theHtml = compiled[0].outerHTML;
                    textarea.value = theHtml;
                    output.html(theHtml);
                });
            };
            scope.$watch("template",function(tpl){
    updateOutput(tpl);
            });
            scope.$watch("data",function(){
                updateOutput(scope.template);
            },true);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
  
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    this.data = {
      name: 'John',
      list: ['one duck','two ducks','three ducks']
    };
    //this.template = "<div>hi</div>";
    var template = '';
    template += '<div>\n';
    template += '  <p>{{data.name}}</p>\n';
    template += '  <ul>\n';
    template += '    <li ng-repeat="item in data.list">{{item}}</li>\n';
    template += '  </ul>\n';
    template += '</div>\n';
    this.template = template;
  });
  
 })();
```

```css
.form-field {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-field span {
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.compiled-template {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
}
.compiled-template textarea {
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.compiled-template .output {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="soApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
      <div class="form-field">
          <span class="form-label">Name:</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="main.data.name" /> <br/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-field">
          <span class="form-label">Template:</span>
          <textarea ng-model="main.template" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea> <br/>
      </div>
      <div>
          <show-compiled-template data="main.data" template="main.template" />
      <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer. I was running into issues using $compile to convert an HTML string with Angular expression, compile it, then turn it back into an HTML string that is populated with data. Before using $timeout the Angular brackets {{}} were still showing up, this fixes it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by providing template to your directive like below.

```
app.directive('compile', function($compile) {
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<p>List of products from {{supplier.name}}</p>
               <p ng-repeat="ref in refs">{{ref}}</p>'
    scope: {
     refs: '='
     supplier: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       # Your code goes here 
    }
}
```

})